# Download multiple html pages from a txt file

Tags: python, shell-script, html, lynx

I have a txt file with several links. I need to access each link in this txt and download / save each page. To access each page, login and password are required. How can I do this by terminal linux / shell script / python? Can lynx help?

Comment: [man wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html)     You might also want to google ways to [pass authengication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272770/wget-with-authentication)

Comment: Do you wish to be prompted for the usernames and passwords or do you want to store them in another file that will be read by the script that downloads the pages? Does each page require a separate username and password or is the same username and password used for all pages? Does each line in the text file contain just a link with no other text or do you need to search a text document that has links interspersed with other text?

Comment: Dear @moonpoint, thanks.I want to store them in another file that will read the script that downloads the pages and each line in the text file contain just a link with other text.|||The site does not let you download the link, but when I'm on the page and give a Ctrl+S or Ctrl+P to download or print (pdf) the page. So I thought I'd use lynx to log in to the page and save each link in the txt file. Do you think it is possible? Do you have any better ideas?

Comment: Dear @nnovich-OK, thanks, but I've tried that already. The site does not let wget download with "--user and --password" or "--user --password --auth-no-challenge"